# Swift calling subclass's overridden method from superclass

Tags: swift, inheritance, polymorphism, subclassing

I was having an issue with a subclass's method getting called that overrode a method, so I created a small app to test it. When the superclass calls a method that its subclass overrides, the superclass's version of the method still gets called instead of the subclass's version, which overrides the superclass's method and should be the method getting called.

Expected output: `sub foo`

Actual output: `super foo`

**Superclass:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        foo()
    }

    func foo()
    {
        println("super foo")
    }
}
```

**Subclass:**

```
class SubclassViewController: ViewController
{
    override func foo()
    {
        println("sub foo")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the class of the object on which touchesBegan is called? Is it SubclassViewController or is it ViewController?

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. I never changed the initial view controller in the storyboard to be a SubclassViewController. Thanks. Put your comment as an answer.

Comment: I'm actually seeing this issue with selectors in a superclass, ios 10, Xcode 8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that the object's class is `SubclassViewController`. Otherwise, it will not have any knowledge of the method which is overriden by subclass

Comment: I just found that I was loading VCs from a storyboard by name, but using "as MyBaseName." They are specified as the correct class in the storyboard, however. The baffling thing is that for SOME of them, the overridden method is called. But not others.

Comment: Seems Swift 4 has no such issue, where even if you type-cast, there was no way of calling super-method without calling sub-class's method first.

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth checking that you're not trying to override in an extension. For some reason the override can't be done in an extension.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this functionality is really stupid! Can't believe it after converting from ObjC! What the heck swift..

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled into this issue in Xcode 8.1 / Swift 3.0

I created a super class with a method stub with the intention of overriding it in my subclass, but calling it from the super and to my surprise the override wasn't being called.

My solution to the problem was to create a protocol. Using the OP's example, my solution looks like this:

Super:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        foo()
    }

}
```

Subclass:

```
class SubclassViewController: ViewController
{
    override func foo()
    {
        println("sub foo")
    }
}
```

Protocol:

```
protocol Fooizer {
   func foo() 
}
```

Protocol extension:

```
extension ViewController : Fooizer{
   func foo(){
      abort() //If you don't override foo in your subclass, it will abort
   }
}
```

Comment: No need for abusing protocol(s). Instead the super-method should throw "`Abstract method called; override and ensure not to call super.`" error (check my profile for license of this quote).